# Haxe + Openfl doesnt working Type not found : HelloWorld

Tags: haxe, openfl

I have just installed haxelib + openfl and i'm just creating a new project called helloworld and i get this error when i try to run it:

```
cmd: "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe/haxelib" run lime build "project.xml" html5 -debug -Dfdb
bin/html5/haxe/ApplicationMain.hx:399: characters 47-57 : Type not found : HelloWorld
Build halted with errors.
```

I didn't change a single line i just tried to run the empty project and i'm getting this error! Help Please

Answer (score 0):

You can use these steps to create a new OpenFL project, and run it:

```
openfl create project HelloWorld
cd HelloWorld
openfl test html5
```

If you have any further issues, you can post on the OpenFL forums at https://community.openfl.org